# $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-module

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module contato due to:  

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'contato' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/nomod?p0=contato
```

Código da minha página:

```
<script>
          checkConnection();
            angular.module("contato", []);
            angular.module("contato").controller("contatoCtrl", function($scope){
                $scope.message="+ cont";


            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser duas coisas. 1: A função `checkConnection();` não está definida e por isso quebra o restante do javascript. 2: faltou inserir o arquivo contatoController.js no seu html.

Comment: Removi a função e o <script></script> com a inclusão, e funcionou. Era uma função javascript normal, provavelmente por isso não funcionou